# How I can use a long int and a long int array in assembly languages

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I write a program that does division and mod operations with a long int and an int array. When I want to write my division operation's result but I can't. I can't figure out the problem, but I think I used the register assignments process from the data section wrong. Please help me. I think I call array and int array wrong from the data section or I have problems with registers using. This is my code:

```
         global    _start

          section   .text
_start:   
          
          mov r9, number        ; rdi stores adress of number array
          mov r12,  0             ; get number of k for determine index of number array
     
          
     L3:                       ;  function begin
     
          mov r15,  0                    ; get number of i because using i of loop register
          mov r14, [digits]          ; get number of digits
          mov r13, [r9 + r12*4]      ; get array number for using array adress. We use 4*k because we take k. index of array     
          
      
          syscall
          cmp r13,  0          ; determine number is negative or positive
          jl  L2               ; if it is negative we goto else part for print minus
          
          ; print blank         otherwise we print blank 
          mov rax, 1
          mov rdi, 1
          mov rsi, blank
          mov rdx, 1
          syscall
          
          jmp L1               ; after printing, jump L1 statement
  
     L2:                       ; if number is negative continiuos here so Else part  
          ; print minus
          mov rax, 1
          mov rdi, 1
          mov rsi, minus
          mov rdx, 1
          syscall   
          
          neg r13              ; convert the negative number to positive number      
      
     L1:                        ; into the loop     
           
          ; division operation  digit = (number/digits)
          mov rax, r13         ; dividend
          cqo
          mov rbx, r14         ; divisor
          idiv rbx              ; after the div operation rbx store division
          mov r10, rax         ; result is egual digit (r10)
         
          
          ; print digit
          add rsp , 8 
          add r10, 48  
          mov rax , 1 
          mov rdi, 1
          push r10
          mov rsi, rsp 
          mov rdx, 1
          syscall
      
          ; mod operation   number = number % digits
          mov rax, r13         ; dividend
          cqo
          mov rbx, r14         ; divisor
          xor rdx, rdx         ; rdx which store reminder be zero
          idiv rbx              ; after the div operation rbx store division    
          mov r13, rdx         ; rdx store reminder and reminder egual number
 
          ; division operation  digits = (digits/10)
          mov rdx, 1
          mov rax, r14         ; dividend
          mov rbx, 10          ; divisor
          div rbx              ; after the div operation rbx store division
          mov r14, rbx         ; result is egual digit (r14)   
   
          inc r15              ; increment the loop register
        
          cmp r15, 9           ; compare loop register with 9 so loop work 8 times
          jl  L1               ; if loop register less than 9 return loop
          
          ; print new line  
          mov rax, 1
          mov rdi, 1
          mov rsi, newline
          mov rdx, 1
          syscall  
          
        
          inc r12            ; increment k by 1  
          

          cmp r12, 8         ; compare k with numberCount
          jl L3              ; if k less than numberCount, goto L3 that is begining write9digits function 
         
         
     Exit:                                  ; if array index(k) greater than numberCount work Exit
          mov       rax, 60                 ; system call for exit
          xor       rdi, rdi                ; exit code 0
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to exit

          section   .data
newline      db       10      ; note the newline at the end
blank        db       ' '
minus        db       '-'
i            dd       0      
k            dd       0      
digits       dd       100000000
number       dd       321762410, 9, 2943018, 0, 19372039, 18, -76241, -208424
```

this code will print this

```
  00000000

  0�0000000

  0�0000000

  0�0000000

  000000000

-0�0000000

-0�0000000

  0_0000000
```

but Acorrding to my c code result must be this:

```
 321762410
 000000009
 002943018
 000000000
 019371039
 000000018
-000076241
-000208424
```

I tried to use qword to convert take integer but nothing changed. After I changed the integers' format to hexadecimal format, nothing changed. Finally, I tried to change [digits] and [r9 + r12*4].

```
          mov r14, [digits]          ; get number of digits
          mov r13, [r9 + r12*4]      ; get array number for using array adress. We use 4*k
```

if I changed the [digits] as 5 and [r9 + r12*4] as 21, I take this output:

```
          mov r14, 5       ; get number of digits
          mov r13, 21      ; get array number for using array adress. We use 4*k
```

```
  400000000

  400000000

  400000000

  400000000

  400000000

  400000000

  400000000

  400000000
```

Comment: If you want to know from an expert about how to do division of long int by int or vice versa, try a compiler: something like `int f(long int a, int b) { return a/b; }`.  Use godbolt.org; play with the various types as needed.

Comment: `mov r13, [r9 + r12*4]`: your `number` is `dd` dwords but you load into `r13` which is a qword. For starters use `movsx` there. What is the random `syscall` doing in the middle of the code? If you instead want long ints (64 bit) as in the question title then use `dq` to define the numbers and also scale by 8 not 4.

Comment: As I've linked multiple times on your previous questions, [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) shows working code for int->string conversion.  For signed integers, the only sensible way I know of is to remember the sign and start with `unsigned tmp = abs(x);` (and do unsigned division).  Signed division with negative numbers will give you negative remainders, so `digit + '0'` doesn't work to get a decimal digit.

Comment: @PeterCordes well that seems to be in the code already, see the `neg r13` just before `L1`.

Comment: @Jester: Oh, yes.  It's still doing signed division so that limits it to a max magnitude of LONG_MAX instead of ULONG_MAX, but the inputs are much smaller than that so that isn't the bug that's giving wrong digits.  Single-step debugging should make it fairly clear what's going on, after fixing the `dd` vs. `dq` issue (and the scale factor to match), or the operand-size of the load.  That was explained in comments on a previous question, but is still not fixed.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I changed dd to dq and I deleted the syscall that was empty. Also, I changed cqo to xor rdx, rdx. Finally, I deleted add rsp, 8 where on the bottom of the printdigit. Now, my output is:
 3!0000000
 000000000
 0�0000000
 000000000
 0c0000000
 010000000
-0�0000000
-0�0000000
I tried to unsigned division and  I investigate "How do I print an integer in Assembly...", but I can't understand and I can't fix my code.  What do I need to do? Could you help me, please? I am sorry, I am new to this job.

Comment: Did you also fix `mov r13, [r9 + r12*4]` to use `*8` to match the 8-byte element size you're using now (`long` instead of `int`)?  But that would only affect loading the number; you definitely wouldn't be getting all zeros in most of the digits, or any non-decimal digits, if you didn't have other bugs.  Are you using GDB to single-step your code and look at register values?  If not, do that, it'll save you lots of time in the long run.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for asm GDB tips.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes I fixed mov r13, [r9 + r12*4] to use *8 but it still doesn't work. I don't use GDB, but I will use it on your advice.  Sir, I can compile my code without bugs but I still don't take the right output. What do you think may be the problem

Comment: Not all bugs are assemble-time errors.  With assembly language especially, it's *very* easy to make a total mess of things at run-time.  The assembler only checks that each individual instruction is valid.  The whole concept of a "debugger" as a program to single-step another program and examine its state is based on the understanding that bugs are a run-time phenomenon.  If only things were so simple that compiling or assembling successfully meant a program didn't have bugs...  But that's not the case.  Your program doesn't do what you want, so it has at least one bug remaining.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sir,  I thank your help. Actually, I learn new things thanks to you. Maybe this project fails but for other projects, I remember your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem revealing review

> ```
> mov r9, number        ; rdi stores adress of number array
> ```

R9 is not the same as RDI. Change the comment. And isn't R9 call-clobbered? (See my improved code below that does not use R9)

> ```
> mov r14, [digits]     ; get number of digits
> ```

What you load here is the initial value (100,000,000) for the **divisor**. And *digits* was defined a dword, therefore loading this value requires writing `mov r14d, [digits]` or `movzx r14, dword [digits]`.

> ```
> mov r13, [r9 + r12*4] ; get array number for using array adress. We use 4*k because we take k. index of array
> ```

The array elements are dwords and so the *4 scale factor is fine, but R13 is a qword register and so you should load the value with sign extension:

```
movsx r13, dword [r9 + r12 * 4]
```

Alternatively, you could define your array elements as qwords and then write:

```
mov   r13, [r9 + r12 * 8]
```

> ```
> syscall
> ```

You have a redundant SYSCALL instruction. To be removed.

The code that deals with negative inputs would look better if written as:

```
    mov  rsi, blank
    test r13, r13      ; determine number is negative or positive
    jns  IsPos         ; if it is positive we print BLANK
    mov  rsi, minus    ; else we print MINUS
    neg  r13           ; convert the negative number to positive number      
IsPos:          
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
L1:
```

> ```
> mov  rbx, r14         ; divisor
> idiv rbx              ; after the div operation rbx store division
> ```

There's no gain in first moving the divisor from R14 into RBX. You can simply write:
`idiv  r14`.

> ```
> ; print digit
> add rsp , 8
> ```

In *print digit*, the `add rsp, 8` operation exists to remove the `push r10` value off the stack. Obviously, you can only do this **after** the push got executed.

```
; print digit
add  r10, 48  
mov  rax, 1 
mov  rdi, 1
push r10         ; (1)
mov  rsi, rsp 
mov  rdx, 1
syscall
add  rsp, 8      ; (1)
```

> ```
> ; mod operation   number = number % digits
> mov rax, r13         ; dividend
> cqo
> mov rbx, r14         ; divisor
> xor rdx, rdx         ; rdx which store reminder be zero
> idiv rbx             ; after the div operation rbx store division
> ```

In the *mod operation*, `xor rdx, rdx` destroys the effort from executing `cqo` which is normal prior to using `idiv`. You *can* use `xor rdx, rdx` but in conjunction with `div` (the unsigned division).

> ```
> ; division operation  digits = (digits/10)
> mov rdx, 1
> mov rax, r14         ; dividend
> mov rbx, 10          ; divisor
> div rbx              ; after the div operation rbx store division
> mov r14, rbx         ; result is egual digit (r14)
> ```

In the part that reduces the divisor by a factor of 10, you have introduced the error of setting RDX equal to 1, where prior to using `div` it should have been zeroed. Also, the quotient from the division is in RAX so move *that* to R14.

### Improved code

The code is not optimal. Number conversion using a shrinking divisor is costlier than using a fixed divisor of 10 and storing backwards.

```
         global    _start

         section   .text
_start:   
          
    xor  r12d, r12d    ; get number of k for determine index of number array
L3:                    ;  function begin
     
    xor  r15d, r15d    ; get number of i
    mov  r14, [divisor]          ; get initial DIVISOR
    mov  r13, [number + r12 * 8] ; get array number for using array address. We use 8*k because we take k. index of array     

    mov  rsi, blank
    test r13, r13      ; determine number is negative or positive
    jns  IsPos         ; if it is positive we print BLANK
    mov  rsi, minus    ; else we print MINUS
    neg  r13           ; convert the negative number to positive number      
IsPos:          
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
L1:
    ; division operation  digit = (number/digits)
    mov rax, r13         ; dividend
    cqo
    idiv r14
    mov  r10, rax        ; result is equal digit (r10)

    ; print digit
    add  r10, 48  
    mov  rax, 1 
    mov  rdi, 1
    push r10             ; (1)
    mov  rsi, rsp 
    mov  rdx, 1
    syscall
    add  rsp, 8          ; (1)
    
    ; mod operation   number = number % digits
    mov  rax, r13        ; dividend
    cqo
    idiv r14
    mov  r13, rdx        ; rdx store remainder and remainder equal number
 
    ; division operation  digits = (digits/10)
    mov  rax, r14        ; dividend
    xor  edx, edx        ; Equivalent and better than `mov rdx, 0`
    mov  rbx, 10         ; divisor
    div  rbx
    mov  r14, rax
    
    inc  r15             ; increment the loop register
    cmp  r15, 9          ; compare loop register with 9 so loop work 8 times
    jb   L1              ; if loop register less than 9 return loop
          
    ; print new line  
    mov  rax, 1
    mov  rdi, 1
    mov  rsi, newline
    mov  rdx, 1
    syscall  
          
    inc  r12            ; increment k by 1  
    cmp  r12, 8         ; compare k with numberCount
    jb   L3             ; if k less than numberCount, goto L3 that is beginning write9digits function 
         
         
Exit:                   ; if array index(k) greater than numberCount work Exit
    mov  rax, 60        ; system call for exit
    xor  rdi, rdi       ; exit code 0
    syscall             ; invoke operating system to exit

          section   .data
newline      db       10      ; note the newline at the end
blank        db       ' '
minus        db       '-'
i            dq       0      
k            dq       0      
divisor      dq       100000000
number       dq       321762410, 9, 2943018, 0, 19372039, 18, -76241, -208424
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working.

Comment: @MustafaYilmaz  I fixed one more error: `mov rbx, 10 ; divisor` `div rbx`  `mov r14, rax` (quotient is in RAX)

Comment: @MustafaYilmaz Just updated my answer. Please try the latest version...